# Rewrite urls with .htaccess file in localhost

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

So I have managed to rewrite urls using the .htaccess file but the redirection messes up the url. For example I try to rewrite this:

```
localhost/mysite/public_html/class/5/
```

into this:

```
localhost/mysite/public_html/index.php?v=class&id=5
```

and I use the following lines in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^public_html/([A-Za-z]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ ./public_html/index.php?v=$1&id=$2 [L,R]
```

but the browser redirects me here (I am using **wamp** on Windows 7):

```
localhost/C:/wamp/www/mysite/public_html/index.php?v=class&id=5
```

Which is wrong and gets me a 403 error. What should I do?

Comment: since when there is a public_html on wamp?

Comment: i created this folder for structure purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unbelievable. The error was a result of Firefox's caching. I used Chrome and it was ok. So I cleared Firefox's cache and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

The problem must come from the ./ in your replacement function (./public_html/index.php). A rewrite rule matches the regex you place between ^ and $ and then replaces ONLY that with your second part. I'm assuming you already have some sort of rewritecond before the rule, so try removing the "./"

Try changing your rewritecond to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Which means that if the requested URL is not a file or directory, then it will follow through and try your rewriterule

Comment: Removing the "./" didn't do it for me. As a rewritecond i have this:
**RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost/mysite/$ [NC]** I'm not sure it's right though.

Comment: I'm on a phone, but make sure those rewritecond are on separate lines right before your rewrite rule. Also ensure you have rewriteengine on and mod rewrite enabled

Comment: I have tried using tons of different rewriteconds with no success. It seems that nobody else has this problem so I can't find any solutions. I have spent 2 days straight trying to figure out why. Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: Have you changed your httpd.config file from "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All"?  It would be within a <Directory> tag

Answer (score 2):

Your rule needs to look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^public_html/([A-Za-z]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /public_html/index.php?v=$1&id=$2 [L,R]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which rules you've got before, but your minimal htaccess should be this one :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^public_html/([A-Za-z]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /mysite/public_html/index.php?v=$1&id=$2 [L,R]
```

Avoid using `./` in your rules, and don't forget the location path must include your `mysite` folder